# Trying to return XML with laravel. wrong parse xml

Tags: php, arrays, xml, laravel, laravel-5

Hi im trying to make a xml file with laravel 5.2.

My function What i commented out i tried, wrong xml parse.

```
    public function createXML() {
        $maps = Maps::get()->toArray();

//        function array_to_xml(array $arr, SimpleXMLElement $xml)
//        {
//            foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
//                is_array($v)
//                    ? array_to_xml($v, $xml->addChild($k))
//                    : $xml->addChild($k, $v);
//            }
//            return $xml;
//        }
        function to_xml(SimpleXMLElement $object, array $data)
        {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    $new_object = $object->addChild($key);
                    to_xml($new_object, $value);
                } else {
                    $object->addChild($key, $value);
                }
            }
        }

//        $xmloutput = to_xml($maps, new SimpleXMLElement('<root/>'))->asXML();
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<rootTag/>');
        to_xml($xml, $maps);

        return Response::make($xml->asXML())->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

[image]

my output array:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Leeuwarden"
    "address" => "Leeuwarden"
    "lat" => 53.20132
    "lng" => 5.80005
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "name" => "Assen"
    "address" => "Assen"
    "lat" => 52.99275
    "lng" => 6.56423
  ]
]
```

Any suggestions on what i am doing wrong?

i'm trying to make a google maps API map with pointers from the database.

Comment: It clearly shows that it doesn't like the `<0>` as XML tags cant be integers. Have you tried naming it differently?

Comment: @DainisAbols How can i change this?

Comment: `$object->addChild($key, $value);` you are setting the keys as tags, you need to change the initial key. `$maps = Maps::get()->toArray();` How do you get this array? Is that a Google class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st option:** get the right structure directly in maps and name the arrays.

**2nd option:** if you can'y change the `$maps` array received, then you can modify the head level by adding check to it:

```
$maps = [
    0 => [
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "Leeuwarden",
        "address" => "Leeuwarden",
        "lat" => 53.20132,
        "lng" => 5.80005,
    ],
    1 => [
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => "Assen",
        "address" => "Assen",
        "lat" => 52.99275,
        "lng" => 6.56423,
    ]
];

function to_xml(\SimpleXMLElement $object, array $data, $level = 0)
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $new_object = $object->addChild(($level == 0) ? 'marker' : $key);
            to_xml($new_object, $value, $level + 1);
        } else {
            $object->addChild($key, $value);
        }
    }
}

$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<rootTag/>');
to_xml($xml, $maps);

header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo $xml->asXML();
```

*Edit:* I checked the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#putting-it-all-together), it seems, that the 1st level needs to be named `marker`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a simpler way with [this package](https://github.com/mtownsend5512/response-xml).

```
$maps = Maps::get()->toArray();

$httpCode = 200;
$headers = [];
$rootXmlTag = 'rootTag';

return response()->xml($maps, $httpCode, $headers, $rootXmlTag);
```